# App crashes due to android.view.InflateException. Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml

I know this question has been asked a million times, but i get this error only on asus zenfone 2. I feel this may be a memory allocation problem. But I am unable to trace the cause as it does cause the app to crash in other phones with lower os versions.

```
01-06 15:42:05.080 24439-24439/com.ikarma.clappilyandroidapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ikarma.clappilyandroidapp, PID: 24439
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #165: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at com.ikarma.clappilyandroidapp.fragment.AddProductFragment.onCreateView(AddProductFragment.java:81)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
  at com.ikarma.clappilyandroidapp.fragment.AddProductFragment.onCreateView(AddProductFragment.java:81) 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 96
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:714)
  at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:65)
  at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:61)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:56)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
  at com.ikarma.clappilyandroidapp.fragment.AddProductFragment.onCreateView(AddProductFragment.java:81) 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

Comment: What is your minimum target API? What is your device API?

Comment: Please show ur XML and java code

Comment: specify your xml and build.gradle here

Comment: share java code and xml.......

Comment: There is a problem in your editext.....

Comment: Jaydip Umaretiya , I had asked it in the correct way. The app doesnt crash on any other phone not in higher versions and neither on lower versions

Comment: my minimum api is 16 and device api is 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the issue is with the XML, and I think it is with the `color` values you are putting for either `textColor`, `background` or other such attributes.

So, you must put your xml code here to identify us the problem.